# Auto-break Cell in longtable Environment

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I try to build a document with a question-and-answer form using the `longtable` environment with two tabulars. The first one is for questions, the second one for answers. If my cell contains more data than free space to the bottom margin of the page, it automatically generates a new page and inserts my content. What I exactly need:
Content inserted to the current page should be as much as possible, and the rest of the information should automatically continue on the next page like in an 'image' environment. The issue breaks down to `longtable` creating a table over many pages without regulating auto-breaks. Any ideas?

[image: Result as I need]

[image: Result as I have]

Comment: Please _always_ provide a full document that shows the problem so people can test answers. However longtable will never break the page within a cell, only between rows. Without any indication of the source though it is not clear what input corresponds with your red lines or what you mean be "with two tabulars" do you mean you have tabular inside longtable?

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure that a typesetting system exists, which could break within a table row. You need to re-work your approach.

However, if you are not scary of low-level LaTeX, you can try my code: 
http://uucode.com/blog/2010/12/06/multi-page-tables-with-inter-row-page-breaks/